# What is the behavior of the following code?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node { 

    int data; 
    struct node *next;
}; 
struct node* insert(struct node *root) {

    root->data = 12; //here
    return root; 
}
int main() {

    struct node *root;
    insert(root);
    return 0; 
}
```

Shouldn't my program crash at the place where I have placed the comment in the `insert` function because I have not initialized it with `malloc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)
You never know what might happen.Crash is still a possibility.

Using uninitialized variabled lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: But when I try to print the value using root->data in insert function it still prints the correct value. Why is it so ? @Gopi

Comment: @user1534214 , Undefined Behavior means anything can happen. It might produce expected/unexpected results, crashes etc. You should not rely on this behavior.

Comment: @user1534214 Link added

Answer (score -1):

just add a printf to make some test:

```
printf("root is %p\n", root);
```

some results:

```
Airbus /tmp » ./a.out
root is 0x7fff50b84a08
Airbus /tmp » ./a.out
root is 0x7fff5d1a6a08
Airbus /tmp » ./a.out
root is 0x7fff5ed7da08
Airbus /tmp » ./a.out
root is 0x7fff5c7f5a08
Airbus /tmp » ./a.out
root is 0x7fff5fb3aa08
Airbus /tmp » ./a.out
root is 0x7fff5c16ea08
Airbus /tmp » ./a.out
root is 0x7fff579a8a08

Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
```

and i got segmentfault in my gentoo:

```
[1]    8390 segmentation fault

gcc version 4.5.4 (Gentoo 4.5.4 p1.2, pie-0.4.7)
```